# Longtable and \endlastfoot question

Tags: longtable

Is there any way to force `longtable` environment to put at least one "regular" (data) line on new page (i.e. between table `\endhead` and `\endlastfoot`)??

There is MWE describing (unwanted) situation:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{17.4cm}

\begin{longtable}{@{}lc@{}}
Date &       Grade
\endhead
%
\bfseries Summary:
\endlastfoot
%
2016-01-01 & A\\
2016-01-15 & B\\
2016-01-01 & A\\
2016-01-15 & B\\
2016-01-01 & A\\
2016-01-15 & C\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

I am not sure, there is probably nothing wrong with resulting output, but in some real cases it could be confusing...

Comment: the simplest way (as documented in the package documentation) is just to move the last line of the table into the last foot.